# javascript call another function on click event

Tags: javascript, function, datetime

I wrote a function called formatAMPM that finds the current time. I want to call the this function when I click on the object named buttonfifteenMins. But I didn't succeed.

I want to update the value of a textbox according to the result from here

```js
function formatAMPM(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

var input = document.getElementById('dateTimeRange');
var buttonfifteenMins = document.getElementById('fifteenMins');

buttonfifteenMins.onclick = function() {
  input.value = formatAMPM(new Date);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dateTimeRange" />
<button type="button" id="fifteenMins">15 min</button>
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `new Date()` in the function call parameter list? Is your script element embedded at the end of the body (after the elements you are targeting)?

Comment: are you using jQuery in your project?

Comment: @mplungjan your snippet adds an additional issue.  Perhaps the input should just be text for simplicity.   The question says "text box".  but you made input type="date"

Comment: Now is a great time to start [using your debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in the browser's debugger, observe the values and results of each operation in your function.  When you do this, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: Please be specific when you say "But i couldn't succeed"  What actually happens that's different from what you intended?

Comment: @ZaInKhAn Why is that important? The code presented is vanilla JS

Comment: @mplungjan just asking because if he is using jQuery so  a lot of code can be optimized as well

Comment: @ZaInKhAn You mean changing `document.getElementById('fifteenMins').onclick` to `$('#fifteenMins').on("click",` - not really a huge optimisation. jQuery is no longer as useful as it used to be

Comment: For in example my answer jQuery would be visible in three lines: `const input = document.getElementById('dateTimeRange');` , `document.getElementById("offsetDiv").addEventListener("click"` and `input.value =`
That's all

Comment: @mplungjan it's not about a single variable

Comment: In this question, it is about TWO elements only. Nothing else is jQuery "optimisable"

Comment: Consider `hours = hours % 12 || 12;` to save a line of code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant this?

I added an offset to the button and the show the date (otherwise why have aDay, aWeek and aMonth?)

I saved you all the button assignments too

```js
const pad = num => String(num).padStart(2, "0");
const aMin = 60 * 1000;
const offsets = {
  "fifteenMins":    15 * aMin,
  "anHour":         60 * aMin,
  "fourHours":  4 * 60 * aMin,
  "aDay":      24 * 60 * aMin,
  "aWeek": 7 * 24 * 60 * aMin
}

function formatAMPM(date, offset) {
  if (offset) date.setTime(date.getTime() + offset)
  let hours = date.getHours();
  let minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12;
  return  `${pad(date.getMonth() + 1)}/${pad(date.getDate())}/${date.getFullYear()} @ ${hours}:${pad(minutes)} ${ampm}`;
}

const input = document.getElementById('dateTimeRange');

document.getElementById("offsetDiv").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  console.log(tgt.id)
  const key = tgt.id;
  const d = new Date();
  let offset = offsets[key];
  if (key === "aMonth") {
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1); // add one month - this will be weird on the 31st of Jan for example
    offset = 0;
  }
  input.value = formatAMPM(d, offset);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dateTimeRange" />
<div id="offsetDiv">
  <button type="button" id="fifteenMins">15 min</button>
  <button type="button" id="anHour">1 hour</button>
  <button type="button" id="fourHours">4 hours</button>
  <button type="button" id="aDay">1 day</button>
  <button type="button" id="aWeek">A week</button>
  <button type="button" id="aMonth">A month</button>
</div>
```